# Protect.exe for AutoLISP code protection

Tags: encryption, lisp, stack-overflow, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I am developing an architectural LISP-based package for a member of the IntelliCAD consortium.  Per recommendations I have found on websites, I have used the Kelvinator to deformat and disguise some of the code.  Now I am attempting to use Protect.exe to encrypt the code.  The exe seemed to work until I tried to put use a folder name in the output file name thus:

```
protect es.lsp L  kelvinated\protected\es.lsp
```

First of all, can I do this?  Will protect.exe work like this, or do the input and output file have to be in the same folder?

Also, one time I tried this and I got a "***stack overflow***" error.  Therefore, I am here.

Comment: I was about to remove the stack-overflow tag because I didn't see what the question had to do with the site, but then I remembered that a stack overflow is an actual error :P

Comment: Does IntelliCAD support the *.fas "Fast, Compiled LISP" format?  Its been a while since I've made new AutoCAD/IntelliCAD commands but AFAIK the *.fas files I've distributed for AutoCAD are pretty secure.

Answer (score 0):

Kelvinator/protect et al are pretty old utilities, do you know the last time they were updated? Subtitle, they may expect old school 8.3 file / folder names.

As for "will this work?", I cannot say, as I use different schemes to protect my work when writing lisp for others (vlx/fas, bricscad's encryptor, my own loader / obfuscators ...).

A stack overflow in this context suggests a recursion error, perhaps when it tries to reconcile the pathing you're providing.

Have you tried to use the DOS short path? Putting the path in quotes? Using forward slashes? Using double backslashes?

What happens if you pass "/?" (and alternates) on the command line, does it provide any help?

Finally, if it refuses to process the files unless they share they same directory you could always front end with with a batch file that does the housekeeping for you.

Michael.